# Подсчёт символов C

Tags: c

изучаю C. В книге есть пример подсчёта символов. Никак не пойму, почему ответ в два раза больше. С чем это связано?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int nc;
    for(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc){
        ;
    }
    printf("%d\n\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы считаете не символы, а байты, а один русский символ занимает 2 байта?

Comment: Можете привести пример, при котором ответ в два раза больше, чем требуется? Возможно, как отметил @andreymal, дело касается в кириллице, т.к. она занимает 2 байта, в отличие от 1-байтовой латиницы?

Comment: @andreymal Я пробовал и латинские символы. Результат тот же

Comment: @4500zenja Примера нет, я просто вводил символы и понял, что результат в 2 раза больше нужного

Comment: @Maksim если Вы вводили по одному символу, то тогда дело в том, что, помимо него, в конец строки неявно записывается нулевой символ `\0`, закрывающий все строки в C перед EOF.

Comment: @4500zenja Все, разобрался. Большое спасибо